# jQuery slide, how to not slide at beginning or end?

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function which slides a certain div to the right or left when I click a button.

```
$(function(){
    $("#prev").click(function(){
        $("#contentcont").animate({'left': '-=110'});
        return false;
    });
    $("#next").click(function(){
        $("#contentcont").animate({'left': '+=110'});
        return false;
    });
});
```

Everything works fine. But what can I do if I havent slided anything yet, I can just slide the whole thing to one side? Right now I can slide to both sides. But I just want to do that if I already slided at least one. Also the same for the end... how can I tell jquery to stop the sliding when I just reached the end?

Thanks in advance. I'm still not a jquery pro...

Comment: And you should also start to upvote answers!

Comment: This is really hard to understand, and I've read the question like five times. Care to explain further?

Answer (score -1):

You could set up a variable to track whether the user has engaged with the UI or not.  Then test the variable in a conditional before executing the function contents.

```
var userEngagedUI = false;
$(function(){
    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if(userEngagedUI){
            $("#contentcont").animate({'left': '-=110'});
        }
        return false;
    });
    $("#next").click(function(){
        userEngagedUI = true;
        $("#contentcont").animate({'left': '+=110'});
        return false;
    });
});
```